# Google Spreadsheet Formula to Use Current Row in Function

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate the product of two different columns (e.g., A & B) for each row on my spreadsheet. For a single row, this would work by using `=PRODUCT(A1:B1)`, but I can't figure out how to get the function to use the current row instead of a manually entered row. I know you can get a reference to the current row using `ROW()`, but I get an error when I try something like `PRODUCT(AROW():BROW())`.

Comment: This question is probably not within the scope of this forum, but I will go ahead and give an answer anyway.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you copy the formula you quoted into another row, or fill it down using Ctrl+D, it will automatically change the reference to the row you are copying/filling to. This is called a "relative reference". If you use the formula `=PRODUCT($A$1:$B$1)`, this is called an "absolute reference", which will not change if copied elsewhere.

You can also use the following formula in any row:

`=A:A*B:B`

which will return the product of the two values in the row the formula is invoked.

Comment: sorry, a reference really is substituted automatically, I just need to copy it in a cell which is not in the edit mode (that is a mode which it enters after double click)

Comment: This actually refers to the first cell in a given column, not the cell of the current row.

Comment: @DissidentRage, what do you mean by "this"?

Comment: Referring to this formula: `=A:A*B:B`

Comment: In that case, I can't replicate what you're saying. `=A:A*B:B` in C5 will return A5*B5.

Comment: remember to specifically use `A:A`, not just `A`

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He asked how to reference the current row. Not how to multiply two columns together. Multiplying two columns together was the end goal.

Comment: @Alex the =A:A*B:B formula does not "multiply two columns together". It multiples two cells together; the two cells in the same row that the formulas is placed. A simpler example without multiplication is =A:A. When that is placed in B6, it will return A6. When placed in B7, it will return A7. It will always reference the current row. So I don't understand how I am not answering the question (other than not being able to communicate the answer very well!).

Comment: @AdamL Oh I was confused about what your answer did. Thanks

Comment: @AdamL I am calculating the sums of the cells across a few columns, and tried to replace =SUM(B9:E9)/3 with =SUM(B:B:E:E)/3 but I get error #NAME?

Comment: @likejudo Yes, that structure won't work in the case of referencing multiple columns. A workaround: `=SUM(INDEX(B:E,ROW(),0))/3`

Comment: Apparently there are still no answers to the question. It's probably either some reserved word in the spirit of `self` in other script/programming languages or it can't be done (possibly due to looping references or something). This would save us from 2px-wide helper columns so much.

Comment: This answer actually does not answer the question, it only solves his specific problem with a different solution. The question was applicable to many things; in my case, getting a specific column but current row from a different spreadsheet via IMPORTRANGE.

Answer (score 72):

One way to do this is using the [=INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function.  There are then a couple ways to approach this (plus a bonus, below):

### =INDIRECT, A1B1 notation

Option 1 uses the `=ROW()` function (and `=CONCAT` to join column and row names) as you were mentioning, and in this case might look like:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("A", ROW())) * INDIRECT(CONCAT("B", ROW()))
```

*(Note: I'm using `x * y` instead of `=PRODUCT(x, y)` because it seems more readable within the answer, given only two factors.)*

If you did this on row 3, it would effectively come up with `A3 * B3` as the formula.

### =INDIRECT, R1C1 notation

Option 2 with `=INDIRECT` is to use a "relative" reference, using what's called "R1C1 notation". This notation is accessed by passing `FALSE` to the (optional) second parameter of `=INDIRECT`, and has two basic forms:

1. Referring to another cell by it's *absolute* position, e.g. `R1C1` always refers to `A1` (first row, first column), `R3C2` always refers to `B3` (third *row*, second *column* – note that the order of row and column is reversed from the `B3` notation). These hold true wherever the references appear on the sheet (they'll always resolve to `A1` and `B3`, respectively).
2. A position *relative to the current cell*, using `R[1]C[1]` for example, which indicates `1` row down, `1` row to the right. Basically, this is the same notation, except that you put the numbers in brackets to reference the number of rows and columns *away from the current cell* (going down and to the right for positive numbers) a particular cell is. While `R[1]C[1]` refers to `1` row down, `1` column to the right, `R[0]C[-1]` would refer to the *current row* (`0` is no change), *1 column to the left* (negative numbers go up for row and to the left for column instead of instead of down and right, respectively).

These two forms can be combined – absolute for row, relative for column, or vice versa.  So if you wanted to multiply the value on the current row in column A to the value on the current row in column B, you could use:

```
=INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE) * INDIRECT("R[0]C2", FALSE)
```

This would always give you what you could think of (***but not express***) as `=AROW() * BROW()`.

*(Side-note: I found [this description of using `=INDIRECT`](http://dsernst.com/2015/05/29/spreadsheet-relative-cell-references/) to be helpful in coming up with the above.*

---

### $A$1 – anchored references (bonus)

Finally, it's probably worth noting that it's possible to reference fixed columns and/or rows using the `$` modifier. Normally, when copy/pasting formulas into other cells, the column and row references change based on the amount of movement: copying a reference to `=A1` from `C2` to `E3` would get you `=C2` (A became C because the reference moved two columns to the right; 1 became 2 because it moved down 1 row).  The `$` notation anchors one or both of these references.

E.g. if you had a reference in to `=$A1` in cell `C1`, and then copied that into `C2`, it would become `=$A2`. This much is unexceptional, because `=A1` would have copied to `=A2` as well. But if you now copied from `C2` to `D3` (one row down *and* one column right), it would become `=$A3`, still *anchored* to column A, and still *changing* the row number.  So if from any column on row 63 (arbitrary example) you put the formula `=$A63 * $B63`, you could then copy/paste that to any other cell on the spreadsheet and it would multiply the values in columns A and B of the row you pasted into.  (Which I think is maybe what you were trying to do?)

*(Also: Note that you can do the same thing with row references - `=A$1` is always row `1`, but `A` can change; `=$A$1` will always be `A1`, no matter where you put the reference to it.)*

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer @lindes

Comment: This is a great answer. I used this in order to use dynamic indirect references on conditional formatting formulas. Very well explained @lindes.

Comment: This is so ugly. How do spreadsheets not have a cleaner solution to what I imagine is a very common requirement?

Comment: @mowwwalker: I think for most common requirements, the `$` notation will get most folks what they want, and that's pretty terse and, once one is familiar with it, easy to grok.  And `=INDIRECT(...)` gives full flexibility to do whatever one wants.  Seems _pretty_ clean to me.  If you've got a better idea, you could always suggest it to someone at Google or Microsoft.

Comment: Great, small misstake on CONCAT syntax :
CONCAT("A", ROW()) -->  CONCAT("A"; ROW())

It is ; (not ,)

Comment: @seb54000: Really?  I don't know why it should be a semicolon.  Indeed, I just opened up a spreadsheet and tried doing a `=concat("a"; row())`, and it converted the semi-colon to a comma.  So, semicolon is allowable, but a comma is not a mistake... unless... am I missing something??

Comment: I put the comment because it was not working for me with a comma. Can’t remember if I was doing it from iPhone app or from browser workstation, if there may be a link.

Comment: Excellent Answer!!!! I Have searched everywhere for this kind of answer! In my opinion, it should be the top answer; people should always explain things like this. Answer like these keep in mind that newcomers will be reading it for years to come. It really helps save thousands of people thousands of hours of frustration! So... Thank you!

Comment: @osirisgothra: Thanks... Well, if people keep upvoting it, without upvoting the accepted answer, it may eventually take top place.  And hey, they've got "for years to come" time to do so, so... it may happen. :)   In the mean time, hopefully others who need this information will scroll enough to find it.   And whenever I'm writing an answer on this (or other SE) site(s), I'll keep aiming for this level of utility and clarity of explanation.  Anyway, gladly done, and thanks for the kind words.